# How to get insert to work for entry widget python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I know there are may questions similar to this and I have looked at them but have not found an answer to my problem.

I have created an entry widget and want to insert a default value. Here is function:

```
def set_Tk_var():
    DP_DR1_BIPS = tk.StringVar()

def entryWidget():

    DP_DR1_BIPS.insert(0, 16)
    entryText = DP_DR1_BIPS.get()
    print (entryText)
```

I get this error:
    DP_DR1_BIPS.insert(0, 16)
AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'insert'

The interesting thing is if I comment out the insert line, I can enter a value in the widget and run this, it does get the value and print it. I am just unable to insert a default.

Comment: Why do you think `insert` should work on a `StringVar`? There's no documentation that says it has that method. To change the value of a `StringVar` you need to call the `set` method on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to call the insert method on DP_DR1_BIPS even though this has no insert method.

Did you mean to use DP_DR1_BIPS.set() instead?
According to [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) website, variables of type StringVar don't have an insert method, but a set method.